# Trouble getting $auth.user data from ng-token-auth in my directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have tried to get the user data information inside an `angular-directive` from the `ng-token-auth` without success.

When I print the `$auth` object the user seems OK, but when I tried to retrieve the user data from `$auth.user` the information is not there.

```
.directive('osAuthorize', function ($auth) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      var needed_roles = attrs['osAuthorize'].split(',');    
      console.log($auth); // prints the full object within the user data
      console.log($auth.user); // prints {}
    }
  };
```

Comment: console is not a snapshot...it will be a reference. If object gets updated will also update in console. Try `console.log(JSON.stringify($auth));` is likely different output. Show the $auth service code

Comment: You are right, but I'm still with the original trouble, how can I pass the `$auth` to a directive in order to evaluate the `user` object in my directive? In fact, I figured out that the directive has been rendered/compiled before the ng-token-auth call its methods, what should have caused this.

Comment: asynchronous ajax calls  cause this. Need to pass a promise from `$auth` ...or....make sure $auth is resolved in router first. Which router are you using?

Comment: solved using `$q.defer().resolve(my_function())` as you suggested. thanks mate!